# Cant set sender name phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I'm setting up a script to send emails from a contact us form. Everything is working great besides the fact that I can't set sender's name properly. I get an error:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value
```

My code looks like this:

```
<?php $eemail = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
 $message = $_REQUEST['message']; $subject = $_REQUEST['subject']; $fname =
 $_REQUEST['name'];

 require("class.phpmailer.php"); $mail = new PHPMailer();  

 $mail->Username = "email";  // SMTP username
 $mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password  $mail->IsSMTP(); 
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  $mail->Host = 'aspmx.l.google.com'; 
 $mail->Port = 25;



 $mail->From = $eemail; $name->FromName = $fname; $mail->Subject =
 $subject;

 $mail->AddAddress("email", "name");


 $mail->WordWrap = 50;

 $mail->IsHTML(true);

 $mail->Body    = $message; $mail->AltBody = $message;

 if(!$mail->Send()) {    echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";    echo
 "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;    exit; }

 echo "Message has been sent"; ?>
```

Comment: Im hoping your email and passwords are examples and not your actual ones.

Comment: Please be more carful!

Comment: add this code  $mail->SetFrom("$eemail ", "$fname");

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati thanks a lot, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code

```
$mail->SetFrom("$eemail ", "$fname");
```

Comment: Setting `From` and `FromName` properties achieves the same as calling `setFrom`, but skips validation, so you should check the return value to be sure it worked. [Read the code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L990).